# JSF: logic based on iteration index

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets, icefaces

Pardon me for the title, that's the best my limited brain can came up this late.

So, i have a list of string, something like [abc, def, ghi].

The question: in JSF, how do I iterate the list and create a string that look like this "abc, def, ghi" (notice the commas)?

For those who have the urge to tell me that I'd better use a Java method to concatenate the string, hear this: every member of the list should be rendered as a separate commandLink.

If plain JSF it would look like:

```
<h:commandLink>abc</h:commandLink>, <h:commandLink>def</h:commandLink>, <h:commandLink>ghi</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that `#{bean.items}` returns `List<String>` or `String[]`, in JSF 1.x you can use JSTL `c:forEach` with `varStatus`. It gives you a handle to [`LoopTagStatus`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) which has a `isLast()` method.

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <h:commandLink value="#{item}" /><c:if test="#{!loop.last}">, </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

In Facelets as shipped with JSF 2.x, same functionality is available by `ui:repeat`.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <h:commandLink value="#{item}" />#{!loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: your solution on <ui:repeat /> didnt work out of the box for me, but it guided me to this forum post http://seamframework.org/Community/SolutionForUirepeatWithVarStatusAndNewParametersFromAndTo which have my answer and more.

thanks..

Comment: It only works on JSF 2.x. You seem to be using JSF 1.x. The first solution is then more applicable on you.